# PHPStorm display working branch name

Tags: git, netbeans, phpstorm

I did not find anything related to this so maybe someone can help me by telling me if there is an option to display the working branch in PHPStorm similar to what NetBeans is offering like in the screenshoot below:

Netbeans - [second_fixes_chip] is the git branch:

[image]

PhpStorm:

[image]

Comment: Not like that (not in Project view panel) -- check status bar -- it should be there. As for showing it in project view -- check plugins -- I think (although unsure) that I've seen one that can do (unless I was confused about something else).

Comment: right, it is there! tnx! you can add as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Actually solution can be found on official JetBrains forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000090784-The-git-branch-bane-doesn-t-appear-on-the-bottom-right-corner

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In PhpStorm (and other JetBrains' IDEs), current VCS branch is displayed in **status bar** (bottom right corner, next to line numbers/encoding).

ATM there is no option to display current branch next to folders in Project View panel. But you can check VCS plugins -- maybe one of them can do what you have asked in the same way as Netbeans do (like [SVNToolBox plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7321?pr=phpStorm) can do for SVN).

Comment: If your status bar is hidden, re-enable it here "View > Status Bar"

Comment: if you can't see the "vcs" section in your status bar, enable it under "VCS > Enable Version Control Integration..."

Answer (score 5):

You won't see the branch name at the same position as it is mentioned in NetBeans, 
you can see this in the bottom right of IDE.

[image: you can see this in the bottom right of IDE.]

Answer (score 4):

[GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) does what you are looking for in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 3):

I used to see the current Git branch at the bottom hand right corner and for some reason it had disapeared.

Right click the status bar at the very bottom and this sweet little menu will appear, letting you select the current git branch.

[image]